# What is the difference between read-only and read only data section?

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc, binutils, nm

Recently, I have dived into GCC Binutils `nm` documentation. I read the description of the symbols' classification and don't understand the differences between `n` and `R` (or `r`) symbols. As the manual says:

for n

> The symbol is in the read-only data section.

R or r

> The symbol is in a read only data section.

So instead of `a` we have `the` and instead of `-` we have space separating two words... It is also quite tricky for google - it seems to me that google is not paying much attention to the presence of `-`.

Comment: Different people writing the manual using slightly different wording for their respective section?

Comment: A section named `read-only` vs another section that is merely read-only?

Comment: Did you investigate some test compiled from a simple source? Probably different sections are read-only. Did you try to find out for _what_ symbols these classifications are used?

Comment: @thebusybee I tried to compile some self-written code that defines a bunch of variables, but I was able to produce only `r` and `R` - for `static const int` and `const int`, respectively. I have not figured out what variable type would trigger `n` symbol during compilation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But programmers are not novelists to use different words to describe the same thing. If there is no reason for the existence of two read-only sections that means that this tool is in really poor condition. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have never heard about `n` and I believe is an error in the documentation.  `N` is a debug symbol.

Comment: @llwafelll While I cant say I know all the ways this is used for sure and so am not posting this as an answer, it appears the difference is that `r`/`R` is for read-only data (as you are familiar) while `n` is for non-loadable read-only data such as the notes section present in some object files (this the "n"). Specifically, any section BFD considers a read-only data section is `r`/`R`; any section that is considered read-only, with contents but not data is `n